# Does the suffix -ify have any inherent characteristics of making letters pronounced which would otherwise be silent?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, suffixes, phonology, silent-letters

It is quite clear that the word "signify" is derived from *sign* and the suffix *-ify*:

- sign + -ify = signify

The letter "g" in the word *sign* is silent but when the suffix is added, it becomes pronounced:

- /ˈsɪ**g**nɪfaɪ/

Although the "g" doesn't get pronounced when another suffix *-able* is added:

- sign + -able = signable ... /ˈsaɪnəbəl/ (no /g/)

Another example is the word [***damnify***](https://www.lexico.com/definition/damnify):

- /ˈdam**n**ɪfaɪ/

Upon the addition of the suffix *-ify* the "n", which would otherwise be silent, becomes pronounced. Now I looked up their etymologies and came to know that those words weren't formed within English. "Damnify" is from Old French [***damnefier***](https://www.lexico.com/definition/damnify) and "signify" is from Old French [***signifier***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/signify) and I suspect they have etymological /g/ and /n/, respectively.

For "signable" [Wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/signable) merely says "sign + -able" and I can't find it in any other etymological dictionary. The reason "signable" doesn't have a /g/, in my opnion, can be attributed to its compounding *within* Modern English; looking at the results from [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=signable%2Csignify&year_start=1500&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) makes my opinion appear correct in that "signable" has zero results and "signify" predates it by over 500 years.

The suffix *-ify* (which we also use to make words in Modern English) is from French [***ifier***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ify).

#### Questions:

I have two closely related questions:

- Does the suffix *-ify* have any inherent characteristic of making consonants pronounced which would otherwise be silent?
- What if I add it to a Modern English word (say *benign* or *align*)? Will it make the "g" pronounced?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is based on a false premise. According to Etymology online the word [signify](https://www.etymonline.com/word/signify#etymonline_v_23506) comes not from 'sign' but from the Latin 'significare' via the Old French 'signifier'. The same source gives the origin of both the noun and verb [sign](https://www.etymonline.com/word/sign#etymonline_v_24110) as the Latin word 'signum' via the Old French 'signe'. The 'gn' in 'signe' and, probably in 'signifier' would have been pronounced rather like 'niy' (I don't have the IPA symbols available) but this would have been more evident in 'signe' than in 'significare'.

English speakers must have transcribed that sound (which does not exist in English) in two ways, one emphasising the 'g' in 'signify', 'significance' and so on and the other emphasising the 'n' in 'sign'. The fact that there are syllables starting with a 'i' following the 'gn' in 'signify' and 'significance' but not in 'sign' was probably a contributing factor. The fact that 'sign' would have been used more widely by the mainly illiterate general population might also have contributed.

Comment: Thanks. I realize that, but the whole point of my question is about the behavior of the suffix ify.

Comment: @Sphinx What I get from this answer is that *-ify* actually reverses the silencing, restoring pronunciation; it doesn't add pronunciation where there wasn't any.

Comment: @Sphinx You said in your question 'It's quite clear that "signify" is derived from _sign_ and the suffix _-ify'_. What I am saying is that that is not clear at all, in fact the sources say that _signify_ is only tangentially related to 'sign' if it is related at all. Therefore trying to derive a general point about the -ify ending from 'sign' and '-ify' is a pointless exercise since they are not related.

Answer (score 0):

There is apparently nothing particular about "-*ify*" and the most probable phenomenon to be associated to this restitution of the g (widely applicable) is the reduction of the long  vowel (/aɪ/, /eɪ/, /u:/ to a short one (/ɪ/, /ʌ/) or simply the  possible choice of a short vowel before non ending "*-gn*" (dignity); the adoption of a long vowel is apparently the rule before ending "*-gn*".

- sign /saɪn/,  signage /ˈsaɪn ɪdʒ/, **BUT** signal /ˈsɪ**g** nᵊl/, signify /ˈsɪ**g** nɪ faɪ/, signature, signalment, signet, significant, …
- assign /ə ˈsaɪn/, assignable /ə ˈsaɪn əb  ᵊl/, assignee /ˌæs aɪ ˈni:/, assignment /ə ˈsaɪn mənt/, **BUT** assignation /ˌæs ɪ**g** ˈneɪʃ ᵊn/, assignat /ˈæs ɪ**g** næt/
- benign /bə ˈnaɪn/, **BUT**  benignant /bə ˈnɪ**g** nənt/, benignity /bə ˈnɪ**g** nət i/
- design /dɪ ˈzaɪn / **BUT** designate, designation, designatory, …
- malign /mə ˈlaɪn/, **BUT** malignant /mə ˈlɪ**g** nənt/, malignancy, malignity
- impugn /u:/, impugnable **BUT** impugnation /ˌɪm pʌ**g** ˈneɪʃ ᵊn/
- reign /reɪn/, **BUT** (*Here, we find as well a change in the digraph.*) regnant /re**g** nənt/, regnal, regnancy
- align /ə ˈlaɪn/, alignment /ə ˈlaɪn mənt/
- arraign /ə ˈreɪn/, campaign /kam ˈpeɪn/,  campaigning /kam ˈpeɪn ɪŋ/
- deign /deɪn/, deigning /ˈdeɪn ɪŋ/
- dignity, dignify, dignitary
- consign, consignment, consignee

Comment: But what determines the vowel length before the ⟨ɡn⟩? (I've done a lot of research on this but to no avail; that is to say, this is a circular argument.)

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul I've asked myself that question  also and haven't done any research, but I do find the coincidence puzzling; it might have a rational explanation.

Comment: This phenomenon also occurs with consonant letter sequences other than <gn>, and also when the shorter word's last vowel is short (hymn/hymnal; solemn/solemnity; bomb/bombard). I suggest the following: the consonant letter sequence after the shorter word's last vowel represent a consonant sound sequence which English doesn't allow in a syllable's coda. So we make one of them silent. But when a suffix beginning with a vowel is added, that sequence's last consonant can now be the new syllable's onset, and the consonant sound sequence is now allowable.

Comment: Your argument appears to lead to no useful generalization; the list of exceptions could be too important (for "mn" there would be fewer exceptions (contemning)). Without much research, I gathered  a list of words that do not verify the contemplated rule: _**lamb** lambing, lambed, **limn**, limned, limning (_ exception: _"limner"), **bomb**, bombing, bombed, bomber, **dumb**, dumber, dumbest, **numb**, numbed, numbing, number, **crumb**, crumbed, crumby, **plumb**, plumbing **thumb**, thumbing, thumber, **quantities of -ng ending words**, bang, long, wing, etc._